# Sending username as a variable in a parse push-notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification

How can i add the current users username in a parse.com push-notification message?

This is the code i have:

```
pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"userStable" equalTo:SecondStable];

pushNotify = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[pushNotify setQuery:pushQuery];
NSString *username = currentUser[@"username"];
[pushNotify setMessage:@"%@ sent you a message", username];
[pushNotify sendPushInBackground];
```

I have `pushQuery` and `pushNotify` as properties in my .h file.

I get an error message saying:

> Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to format your message string incorrectly.

```
[pushNotify setMessage:@"%@ sent you a message", username];
```

should be:

```
[pushNotify setMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ sent you a message", username]];
```

As your code stands now, I believe the error is mistaking "username" for a second argument in `setMessage`, thus the error message: "Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2."

Comment: Oh, forgot to format the string like that! Thanks for helping me out!!